# arrange array order to match shuffled array

Tags: perl

I'm having a big headache here. I want to shuffle an array of positions and then shuffle another array using the same pattern:

```
use warnings;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @order = qw/1 3 2 0/;
my @words = qw/test this a is/; 
@new_order = shuffle(@order);
#some code.... ?
print @words; #this is a test
```

Result:

```
randomized words: this a is test.
randomized Order: 0 2 1 3.
sort: this is a test.
```

next run

```
randomized words: test a this is.
randomized Order:  2 3 1 0.
sort: this is a test.

and so on...
```

i have tried and searched but to be honest im just utterly puzzled :/

Comment: `@words[@new_order]` is called a "slice" in Perl.

Comment: I know thats along the right track but that alone doesn't do it. It will create a matching random order BUT the indexes do not spell "this is a test".

Comment: Your output does not match your code. Printing `@words` as provided will always produce `testthisais`.

Comment: As for your question, it sounds like you want a [hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), which maintains the association of keys to values.

Comment: you can use keys on an array also.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking because your values are *already* shuffled something like that. Your question says that you want to *"shuffle an array of positions and then shuffle another array using the same pattern"*, but your code shows two arrays - the first containing the indexes to get the second one back in the correct order, and says you want a way to get the phrase back in the correct order. Which is it, please?

Comment: Presumably [this question on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1151703) is your own? Apart from that question being phrased significantly differently, it's polite to say if you have asked the same question elsewhere to save people (like me) wasting their time on solving an answered question

Comment: Are you trying to do `my @new_ordered_words[@new_order] = @words[@order]`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to shuffle two arrays using the same pattern, do:

```
use warnings;
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @order = qw/1 3 2 0/;
my @words = qw/test this a is/;

my @shuffle = shuffle(0..$#order);
my @new_order = @order[@shuffle];
my @new_words = @words[@shuffle];
```

If it is something more complicated, it would really help to see the code that generates your sample output (after the shuffling part that you are asking for help with).

Comment: If you're saying `@new_words[@new_order]` should be the same as `@words[@order]` then you clearly haven't tested it. `@new_words` needs to be the *inverse* of the shuffle mapping, and all you are doing is applying the same mapping twice

Comment: @Borodin: I can see that reading of the question as likely, but not definite.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution just provides the `some code.... ?` comment in your own program. But the call to `shuffle` is superfluous, and it works only because you have presumably chosen your numbers that way

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @order = qw/ 1 3 2 0 /;
my @words = qw/ test this a is /; 

my @new_order = shuffle(@order);

@words = @words[@order];
print "@words\n";
```

### output

```
this is a test
```

Comment: only other way to describe it is a permutating array. words is randomized, Order is randomized, but the index's 1,2,0,3 (for example) point to the correct location in the Words array to produce "this is a test" so i also need to output the new order array and the new word array (as they should now have mutated)

Comment: @sean: Please explain what you need that my solution doesn't provide. And why are you shuffling already-shuffled indexes? As soon as you do that they're useless for rebuilding the original phrase, and there's no way of knowing the correct order of either the phrase or the indexes. It often helps to explain your problem if you describe the underlying purpose of what you're writing. Where do `@order` and `@words` really come from?

Comment: I think this was answered [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1151703). See the reply by choroba.